# Как правильно задать SERVER_NAME для веб-приложения?

Tags: python, flask

В учебных целях разрабатываю веб-приложение, в данный момент пытаюсь реализовать функцию по сбросу пароля через ссылку отправленную на email. Генерирую ссылку с помощью url_for и столкнулся с проблемой что он создает ссылку вставляя 'localhost' вместо сервера гитхаба на котором я запускаю приложение. Из предложенных решений данной проблемы было только указание `SERVER_NAME`

```
app.config["SERVER_NAME"] = 'test.test'
```

но к сожалению что-то пошло не так, приложение теперь вообще не запускается и появилась ошибка:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py:1781: UserWarning: Current server name 'localhost' doesn't match configured server name 'test.test'
  return self.url_map.bind_to_environ(
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 17:50:21] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
```

Comment: Локально не запускается? Или на сервере?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA на сколько я понимаю, я работаю через сервер cs50, через него и запускал приложение ранее. сейчас пытаюсь заменить localhost на адрес этого сервера (test.test поставил условно) чтобы получить корректную ссылку

Comment: Мой вопрос не в этом, я спрашиваю, ошибку 404 и warning про sever name получаете локально или на сервере?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA я это вижу как ошибки на сервере (ошибку в терминале я скинул, в браузере пишет "The requested URL was not found on the server")...но опыт у меня нулевой, могу ошибаться или чего-то не понимать